# mysql_query(): how to check whether any rows are updated in case of UPDATE SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am using mysql_query() to execute UPDATE SQL on my table. I want to know whether the query has updated any row or not.

```
    // $query contains UPDATE SQL
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
if(!$result) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}
```

I tried to check value of $result, but it always comes out to be 1 for both cases(0 or more than 0 rows updated).

Can anyone please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php). It returns the number of modified rows in the last query run.

```
$numRows = mysql_affected_rows($connection).
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php).

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, you may also find this answer in SQL via the [`ROW_COUNT() function`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count), although `mysql_affected_rows` is better for this task.