# SQL, PHP update query

Tags: php, sql

I was wondering if there is any way to check if the update query has executed successfully or else I will execute insert query.

```
$record = mysql_query("update table set a='$b', b='$c' where id = '$id' "); 
echo $record; // returns always 1;
```

Thank You.

Comment: You Should keep php code outside of quotes. 

Try this `$record = $mysql_query("update table set a='".$b."', b='".$c."' where id = '".$id".' ");`

Comment: oh i tried that but its not working!!but thanks for the help!

Comment: Using prepared statements would solve your problem.  **By building SQL statements with outside variables, you are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.  http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has many examples in detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the **mysql_affected_rows** function to find the number of records affected. Please see following code.

```
 $record = mysql_query("update table set a='$b', b='$c' where id = '$id' "); 
 $total_rows = mysql_affected_rows($conn);
 echo $total_rows;
```

where $conn is the connection object

Answer (score 2):

It will be like

```
$records = mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET a='$b', b='$c' WHERE id = '$id' "); 
$affected_rows = mysql_affected_rows($records);
if($affected_rows >= 1) {
    echo "Updated ".$affected_rows." rows";
}
```

Need to remove `$` before `mysql_query`.And consider that `table` is your **table name** and also makesure that your connection to the DB is **active**.

And Try to avoid `mysql_*` statements due to the entire `ext/mysql PHP` extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix `mysql_*`, is officially deprecated as of `PHP v5.5.0` and will be **removed in the future**.

There are two other `MySQL` extensions that you can better Use: `MySQLi` and `PDO_MySQL`, either of which can be used instead of `ext/mysql`.

Comment: right now i dont want to use mysqli & pdo_mysql i need some simple solution in mysql only!! thanks for the help!!

Comment: I just suggested only....consider that I have given solution in `mysql` only @Pooja

Answer (score 1):

Try this ... It returns the number of modified rows in the last query run.

```
$Rows = mysql_affected_rows($record).
```

example $Rows = 1, 2, 3 etc......

[mysql_query(): how to check whether any rows are updated in case of UPDATE SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361524/mysql-query-how-to-check-whether-any-rows-are-updated-in-case-of-update-sql)

Answer (score 1):

**`mysql_affected_rows()`** is what you need.

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

```
mysql_query("UPDATE mytable SET used=1 WHERE id < 10");
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
    echo 'You updated '.mysql_affected_rows(). 'rows.';
} else {
    echo 'Nothing updated';
}
```